# What happens to the signal/slot connection if the pointer is pointing to a new object

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a uploader with the following code:

```
if(!_canceled) {
    _reply = _accessManager.put(request, item);

    if(_reply) { 
        _currentItem = item;

        bool status = connect(_reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(reportUploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
        pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "StorageProvider(): connection uploadProgress(qint64, qint64), status", pantheios::boolean(status));
        status = connect(_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handleFinishedRequest()));
        pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "StorageProvider(): connection finished(), status", pantheios::boolean(status));

    } else {
        emit noReply();
        pantheios::log(pantheios::error, "StorageProvider(): no reply", item.toUtf8());
    }
```

Then in the finished slot I do this:

```
QNetworkReply *reply =  qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());

if(reply->error() > QNetworkReply::NoError) { 
    pantheios::log(pantheios::error, "StorageProvider(handleFinishedRequest) ", reply->errorString().toUtf8());

    if((reply->error() == QNetworkReply::TemporaryNetworkFailureError) || (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::ContentReSendError)) {
                    // retry the last request
        _reply = accessManager.put(reply->request(), _currentItem);
    }

} else {
    ...
}
```

This StorageProvider will be able to handle different request and the reply will have different connections depending on in what function it is created. The reason why the reply is a member variable is so that I can delete it before I do my next request.

So, my question is, do I have to do the connection again if I repoint the reply? Is the slot/signal connected to the pointer or the object? Also, is there any better way to delete the old reply?

Edit: Changed the code to this for the handeler of a finished request;

```
if(_currentReply->error() > QNetworkReply::NoError) { 
    pantheios::log(pantheios::error, "StorageProvider(handleFinishedRequest) ", _currentReply->errorString().toUtf8());

    if(((_currentReply->error() == QNetworkReply::TemporaryNetworkFailureError) || (_currentReply->error() == QNetworkReply::ContentReSendError)) && (_currentRetries < 4)) {

        QNetworkRequest lastRequest = _currentReply->request();
        _currentReply->deleteLater();

        _currentReply = _accessManager.put(lastRequest, _currentItem);

        if(_currentReply) { 

            bool status = connect(_currentReply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(reportUploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
            pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "StorageProvider(retry): connection uploadProgress(qint64, qint64), status", pantheios::boolean(status));
            status = connect(_currentReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handleFinishedRequest()));
            pantheios::log(pantheios::debug, "StorageProvider(retry): connection finished(), status", pantheios::boolean(status));

        } else {
            emit noReply();
            pantheios::log(pantheios::error, "StorageProvider(retry): AccessManager no reply");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signal is connected to the object, not to the pointer variable, so you have to make new connections each time.

And to delete the reply, just call `deleteLater()` at the beginning of the `finished()` slot:

```
QNetworkReply *reply =  qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
reply->deleteLater();
```

that way it will be deleted at the end of the slot execution.

---

You can avoid using `sender()` by wrapping each request (the initial one plus all the retries) inside its own `QObject` derived class:

```
class PutRequest : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
private:
     QNetworkAccessManager *_manager;
     QNetworkReply *_reply;
     QIODevice *_item; // Or whatever type the second parameter of put is
public:
     explicit PutRequest(QNetworkAccessManager *manager, QNetworkRequest *request, QIODevice *item, QObject *parent = 0)
       : QObject(parent), _manager, _reply(0), _item(item) 
     {            
         _reply = _manager.put(request, item);
         connectSignalsAndSlots();
     }       

private:
     void connectSignalsAndSlots() {
         // to delete the reply if the PutRequest object is destroyed
         reply_->setParent(this);
         // since the reply is encapsulated, the object has to emit its own
         // upload progress signal
         connect(_reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
         connect(_reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(handleFinishedRequest()));
     }

private slots:
     void handleFinishedRequest() {
         _reply->deleteLater();
         if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
               pantheios::log(pantheios::error, "StorageProvider(handleFinishedRequest) ", reply->errorString().toUtf8());

         if((_reply->error() == QNetworkReply::TemporaryNetworkFailureError) || (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::ContentReSendError)) {
            // retry the last request
            _reply = _manager.put(_reply->request(), _item);
            connectSignalsAndSlots();
         }

         } else {
         ...                 
             emit finished(this);
         }         
     }
signals:
     void uploadProgress(qint64, qint64);
     // emitted when the upload is successful (after the possible retries)
     void finished(PutRequest*);
};
```

And you would create the request like this:

```
if(!_canceled) {
    PutRequest *putRequest = new PutRequest(_accessManager, request, item);

    // and you connect putRequest object signals to whatever you connected _reply to
```

Comment: anthing else i should keep in mind when trying to do retry logic? is there a good way practice to it when it comes to qt? ways to keep track on what upload im retyring etc. atm i only have one request at the time and then saves the upload item to be able to use it when retyring.

Comment: and what happens if i use the reply's request and then delete the reply?

Comment: The only other problem with you code, is that you should normally avoid using `sender()` (the Qt docs explain why). You could create a `QObject` derived class to handle each download, with a `_reply` member, the initial request and its own `finished()` slot, and you can do the retries using that same "download" object.

Comment: `QNetworkRequest` isn't linked to the `QNetworkReply` object, so you can copy it safely and delete the reply afterward.

Comment: so it wont work if the class has a "currentItem" etc that is the current object being uploaded? the class will only handle one call and never start a new one until that one is finished. is that a way to go?

Comment: im not too sure how to use this code inside the storageprovider. where does it get the accessManager from?

Comment: I just re-edited the code to fix that. The accessManager is passed to the constructor too.

Comment: what is the Download object? also, can you delete the reply and then get its request from it?

Comment: Download is just the PutRequest object, I renamed it... And `deleteLater()` doesn't delete its target immediately, you can use the object until the end of the slot.

Comment: so this should be the best way to handle it? i want to be able to do a few reties and then emit finished when it has done all it can. my current solution just keeps getting more and more... unstructured and this seems to be a good solution. thank you very much. also, u had a look at my other question which is directly linked to this, so how should i stored the item?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9134/discussion-between-alexisdm-and-chikuba)