# Resending a post/put request without having the original data

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

I have a question that has been stumping me recently.  I am creating a simple web browser to interact with a single website for user management of a product.  The issue that I am currently having is this: A user can upload a new file though the ui with a basic web form.  Upon selecting to upload, the request will fail with an error code of 205, which is:

QNetworkReply::ContentReSendError - the request needed to be sent again, but this failed for example because the upload data could not be read a second time.

If the user attempts to upload again, the file will upload without error.  To fix this, I would like to detect if there was an error, and if so, resend the request.

My issue is that I don't have the data to go with the request.  I can retrieve the request itself, but not the data.  I imagine my solution to look like the nested if in [this stack overflow question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780255/what-happens-to-the-signal-slot-connection-if-the-pointer-is-pointing-to-a-new-o)

```
if((reply->error() == QNetworkReply::TemporaryNetworkFailureError) || (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::ContentReSendError)) {
     // retry the last request
     _reply = accessManager.put(reply->request(), _currentItem);
}
```

However, this user has access to the _currentItem because they created the request originally in their program, while mine is being created on the fly.  Is there some way that I can capture the data being sent, or cache it? I had hoped that the QNetworkAccessManager stored previous requests for an easy retry, but I am not seeing anything like that.  Thanks for any insight and help!

**EDIT**

For clarification: is there anyway to use a QNetworkAccessManager to get both the request and data for a post/put that was not defined in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways, but as-is the feature doesn't exist.

1. Edit Qt's source code to add it directly to `QNetworkAccessManager`, *or*
2. Implement it as a caching-only HTTP proxy that runs in the same process. The proxy's implementation can use a nested `QNetworkAccessManager` to execute the requests on the real network. The implementation would need to decode the incoming request, re-build the `QNetworkRequest` header, and pass it to the nested manager along with any of request's data. At that point you can set aside the data, and implement a retry at the proxy level.

It'd be probably less work and hassle to implement option 1, but some projects are irrationally averse to modifying Qt, so I'll put option 2 out there for such cases.

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate.  I will keep looking for another solution.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Using Python with PyQt, I solved a similar problem by using a function decorator that saves the request in a lambda function and resends it if it fails. Maybe a similar structure is possible in C++.

In my particular situation, the application had to work with an OAuth2 system that handed out tokens which were only valid for one hour (and could not be refreshed; implicit grant). Thus it could be that after this period of an hour, the user would suddenly get an "Not authenticated" response to one of his requests, which of course is not really user-friendly. So I thought, I'd catch this 401 response, let the user reauthenticate, and then resend the last request that failed.

In my subclass of QNetworkAccessManager, I decorated my HTTP functions (get, put, post, etc) with a function called requires_internet_connection, so my get function for example looks like

```
 @check_network_accessibility
 def get(self, url, callback, *args, **kwargs):
    """ Perform a HTTP GET request """
    ...
```

And the decorator looked as follows:

```
def check_network_accessibility(func):
    """ Decorator function, not to be called directly.
    Buffers the network request so that it can be sent again if it fails the first time, due to an invalidated 
    OAuth2 token. In this case the user will be presented with the login 
    screen again. If the *same* user successfully logs in again, the request 
    will be resent. """

    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(inst, *args, **kwargs):
        if inst.logged_in_user:
            # Create an internal ID for this request
            request_id=uuid.uuid4()
            current_request = lambda: func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
            # Add tuple with current user, and request to be performed
            # to the pending request dictionary
            inst.pending_requests[request_id] = (
                inst.logged_in_user['data']['id'], 
                current_request)
            # Add current request id to kwargs of function being called
            kwargs['_request_id'] = request_id
        return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper
```

Summing up, I check if a user is logged in, and only then I store the request to be sent, completely with passed arguments and all, in a lambda function and store it in a pending_requests dictionary with a unique uuid as a key. I inject this unique uuid into the kwargs (with the key _request_id) of the function to be called, so that if the request is successful, I can use this uuid to remove it from the dictionary containing pending requests (in other words: the clean up). You can do this in the callback function of your QNetworkReply if it finishes without problems.

If the request is not successful however, the user gets presented with a login window, and if he or she successfully logs in again a function is called which traverses the dictionary of pending requests and tries to execute the again:

```
def handle_login(self):
    """ Handles the login event received after login. """
    self.get_logged_in_user(self.set_logged_in_user)

def set_logged_in_user(self, user_data):
    """ Callback function for handle_login; get_logged_in_user"""
    # Parse received data about logged in user
    self.logged_in_user = json.loads(safe_decode(user_data.readAll().data()))

    # If user had any pending requests from previous login, execute them now
    for (user_id, request) in self.pending_requests.values():
        if user_id == self.logged_in_user['data']['id']:
            request()
    self.pending_requests = {}
```

The reason that I use a dictionary is that multiple requests can be sent in parallel in Qt and they of course can all fail when the user has to reauthenticate. I want them all to be tried again after the same user logs in again.

As I said earlier, I know this is Python which works completely different from C++ (which I barely know anything about), but I hope it illustrates the principle well enough to lets one think of a similar structure in C++